# Does Perseverance have a SAM-like instrument?

Tags: perseverance, curiosity, instrument

Curiosity had an instrument called SAM onboard that did gas chromatography and mass spectrometry. Do any of the instruments on Perseverance include these capabilities? If not, why were they deemed unnecessary for Perseverance's missions?

Comment: uhoh! [Will the Mars 2020 rover's sensitivity to methane be better than Curiosity's?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/36901/12102)